# Edit an old georeference raster projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, mapping

I have created a map from a picture. And now I have some more detailed pictures and **georeferenced** them. Is there any way to **quickly** **access** **them** later on.

I mean everything is fine with georeferencing. The picture is projected right where it shall be at the end. But I would like to know if there is a way to add some reference points or even delete some.

I know I could delete the picture and load the raster again and start from a new georeferencing.

So is there a possibility to edit georeferenced pictures?

Comment: Does some one know how to re-georeference a tif ?
I want to readjust some picture. Thank you all

Comment: Sorry but thats no answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/109289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you can refine the GCP later, write the georeferencing result to a vrt file using the GDAL batch conmmandline export.

You can edit that later with any text editor, and add additional GCP's.

Re-georeferencing a tif is more complicated, because the first round you georeference ageianst pixel coordinates, while the second run uses the coordinates of the defined CRS. At least with the QGIS georeferencer.

Comment: Well that would a solution, but I think I'm then faster when I just do the whole thing again. Anyway thanks for the workaround and explainations.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this helps, but I had an issue with georeferencing satellite images on top of basemaps. The images were not taken from a true vertical position, and as such they could not be georeferenced perfectly.
I used the Plugin "Freehand raster georeferencer" which enabled me to massively improve the accuracy on many occasions.